# Are "that's it" and "that's all" interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Are "that's it" and "that's all" interchangeable? Is there any specific case where I should use one instead of the other?

Comment: Can you provide some example sentences so we have a broader context for these expressions?

Comment: What about *"That's all it is?"*

Comment: I think the choice depends on the regional preferences of the people you are speaking to. I've noticed that in some places, saying "that's all" would invariably lead to a response of "huh?", "sorry?", "what did you say?".

Answer (score 3):

*That's it* is an expression that means:

> **1** that is the main point or difficulty: *“Is she going?” “That's just it—she can't make up her mind.”* **2** that is enough or the end: *okay, that's it, you've cried long enough.*
>
> Ref: The OED

Or

> 1. used to say that something has ended
>      *Well, that's it, we've finished - we can go home now.*
>      That's it! I'm not putting up with any more of her rudeness.
> 2. used to say that something is correct
>      *You switch the computer on at the back. That's it.*
>
> Ref:Cambridge

*That's all* doesn't seem to be an expression all by itself, but means that *there's nothing more to it*, *that's all you have to do*, etc.

So in some cases, as in the second example from the Cambridge Dictionary, they could be used the same way with a slight difference in meaning.

Comment: "That's all doesn't seem to be an expression all by itself" -- You forget the Merrie Melodies Porky Pig signoff: "That's all, folks!" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNEd0_rm6kU

Comment: What about "Well, that's all, we've finished"? Isn't that sentence correct?

Comment: Or, "is that all?"  "Yes, that's all."

Answer (score 1):

They are more or less interchangeable when they indicate the peremptory end of a discussion. On most other occasions, they are not.

Answer (score -1):

That's it - used when something has concluded

That's all - used to indicate "only" or "purpuse": "I wanted to talk to you, that's all.

Comment: Please add objective sources when answering questions.